# Is there a log function that will add the log invocation to the control-flow in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, webdriverjs

Is there a log function in Protractor that will add the log invocation to the control-flow?

Or is there a function that exposes the control-flow for me to leverage?

Clearly, `console.log` will log to the console outside of the control-flow (so at the "wrong" time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the control flow reference by calling:

```
browser.controlFlow()
```

Then you can e.g. call:

```
browser.controlFlow().execute(function () {
    console.log("foo");
});
```

See [Protractor API entry for controlFlow](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.controlFlow).